# Navbar Logo not getting centered horizontally in responsive mode

Tags: html, css

Can anyone help me out the figure out where I went wrong in CSS?
My navbar's logo is not getting centered horizontally when I check in responsive design.
Please help me to figure this CSS out

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Segoe UI", Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-seriff;
}

.navbar {
  display: flex;
  position: sticky;
  place-content: center;
  height: 96px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1320px) {
  .nav_options {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  nav {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
  }
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  width: 100vw;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.nav_options ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.nav_options ul li {
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 0 18px;
}

.nav_options ul li a {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav_options ul li a:hover {
  color: rgb(100, 100, 100);
  transition-duration: 450ms;
}

.nav_options ul li a svg {
  padding: 5px;
  width: 15px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Exercise 6 - Navbar using Flexbox</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="navbar">

      <nav>
        <a class="logo" href="https://www.ultraedit.com/downloads/ultraedit-download-thank-you/">
          <img src="https://www.ultraedit.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/01/Dark-logo.png" alt="nav_logo" class="logo" width="200">
        </a>
        <div class="nav_options">
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Products<svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                  <path d="M6 9L11.2929 14.2929C11.6262 14.6262 11.7929 14.7929 12 14.7929C12.2071 14.7929 12.3738 14.6262 12.7071 14.2929L18 9" stroke="#141B34" stroke-width="1.5" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
                </svg>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Pricing<svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                  <path d="M6 9L11.2929 14.2929C11.6262 14.6262 11.7929 14.7929 12 14.7929C12.2071 14.7929 12.3738 14.6262 12.7071 14.2929L18 9" stroke="#141B34" stroke-width="1.5" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
                </svg>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Resources<svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                  <path d="M6 9L11.2929 14.2929C11.6262 14.6262 11.7929 14.7929 12 14.7929C12.2071 14.7929 12.3738 14.6262 12.7071 14.2929L18 9" stroke="#141B34" stroke-width="1.5" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
                </svg>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">About us<svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                  <path d="M6 9L11.2929 14.2929C11.6262 14.6262 11.7929 14.7929 12 14.7929C12.2071 14.7929 12.3738 14.6262 12.7071 14.2929L18 9" stroke="#141B34" stroke-width="1.5" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
                </svg>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#"><svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                  <path d="M5 5.82759H7.7M11 5.82759H9.5M7.7 5.82759H9.5M7.7 5.82759V5M9.5 5.82759C9.18351 6.95937 8.52075 8.02923 7.76429 8.96946M5.83571 11C6.44723 10.4377 7.13788 9.74802 7.76429 8.96946M7.76429 8.96946C7.37857 8.51724 6.83857 7.78558 6.68429 7.45455M7.76429 8.96946L8.92143 10.1724" stroke="#141B34" stroke-width="1.5" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
                  <path d="M13.5 19L14.3333 17M18.5 19L17.6667 17M14.3333 17L16 13L17.6667 17M14.3333 17H17.6667" stroke="#141B34" stroke-width="1.5" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
                  <path d="M14 10V8C14 5.17157 14 3.75736 13.1213 2.87868C12.2426 2 10.8284 2 8 2C5.17157 2 3.75736 2 2.87868 2.87868C2 3.75736 2 5.17157 2 8C2 10.8284 2 12.2426 2.87868 13.1213C3.75736 14 5.17157 14 8 14H10" stroke="#141B34" stroke-width="1.5" stroke-linecap="round" />
                  <path d="M10 16C10 13.1716 10 11.7574 10.8787 10.8787C11.7574 10 13.1716 10 16 10C18.8284 10 20.2426 10 21.1213 10.8787C22 11.7574 22 13.1716 22 16C22 18.8284 22 20.2426 21.1213 21.1213C20.2426 22 18.8284 22 16 22C13.1716 22 11.7574 22 10.8787 21.1213C10 20.2426 10 18.8284 10 16Z" stroke="#141B34" stroke-width="1.5" />
                  <path d="M4 16.5C4 17.9045 4 18.6067 4.33706 19.1111C4.48298 19.3295 4.67048 19.517 4.88886 19.6629C5.39331 20 6.09554 20 7.5 20" stroke="#141B34" stroke-width="1.5" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
                  <path d="M20 7.5C20 6.09554 20 5.39331 19.6629 4.88886C19.517 4.67048 19.3295 4.48298 19.1111 4.33706C18.6067 4 17.9045 4 16.5 4" stroke="#141B34" stroke-width="1.5" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
                </svg>
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>
</body>

</html>
```

Please correct me – I'm new to making websites.

Answer (score 0):

Consider applying `display: none` instead of `visibility: hidden` on the `.nav_options`. With `visibility: hidden`, the element still takes up layout space but is visually hidden. With `display: none`, the element is completely removed from any layout calculations, thus allowing the logo to be centered.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Segoe UI", Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-seriff;
}

.navbar {
  display: flex;
  position: sticky;
  place-content: center;
  height: 96px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1320px) {
  .nav_options {
    display: none;
  }
  nav {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
  }
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  width: 100vw;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.nav_options ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.nav_options ul li {
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 0 18px;
}

.nav_options ul li a {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav_options ul li a:hover {
  color: rgb(100, 100, 100);
  transition-duration: 450ms;
}

.nav_options ul li a svg {
  padding: 5px;
  width: 15px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Exercise 6 - Navbar using Flexbox</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="navbar">

      <nav>
        <a class="logo" href="https://www.ultraedit.com/downloads/ultraedit-download-thank-you/">
          <img src="https://www.ultraedit.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/01/Dark-logo.png" alt="nav_logo" class="logo" width="200">
        </a>
        <div class="nav_options">
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Products<svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                  <path d="M6 9L11.2929 14.2929C11.6262 14.6262 11.7929 14.7929 12 14.7929C12.2071 14.7929 12.3738 14.6262 12.7071 14.2929L18 9" stroke="#141B34" stroke-width="1.5" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
                </svg>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Pricing<svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                  <path d="M6 9L11.2929 14.2929C11.6262 14.6262 11.7929 14.7929 12 14.7929C12.2071 14.7929 12.3738 14.6262 12.7071 14.2929L18 9" stroke="#141B34" stroke-width="1.5" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
                </svg>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Resources<svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                  <path d="M6 9L11.2929 14.2929C11.6262 14.6262 11.7929 14.7929 12 14.7929C12.2071 14.7929 12.3738 14.6262 12.7071 14.2929L18 9" stroke="#141B34" stroke-width="1.5" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
                </svg>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">About us<svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                  <path d="M6 9L11.2929 14.2929C11.6262 14.6262 11.7929 14.7929 12 14.7929C12.2071 14.7929 12.3738 14.6262 12.7071 14.2929L18 9" stroke="#141B34" stroke-width="1.5" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
                </svg>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#"><svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                  <path d="M5 5.82759H7.7M11 5.82759H9.5M7.7 5.82759H9.5M7.7 5.82759V5M9.5 5.82759C9.18351 6.95937 8.52075 8.02923 7.76429 8.96946M5.83571 11C6.44723 10.4377 7.13788 9.74802 7.76429 8.96946M7.76429 8.96946C7.37857 8.51724 6.83857 7.78558 6.68429 7.45455M7.76429 8.96946L8.92143 10.1724" stroke="#141B34" stroke-width="1.5" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
                  <path d="M13.5 19L14.3333 17M18.5 19L17.6667 17M14.3333 17L16 13L17.6667 17M14.3333 17H17.6667" stroke="#141B34" stroke-width="1.5" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
                  <path d="M14 10V8C14 5.17157 14 3.75736 13.1213 2.87868C12.2426 2 10.8284 2 8 2C5.17157 2 3.75736 2 2.87868 2.87868C2 3.75736 2 5.17157 2 8C2 10.8284 2 12.2426 2.87868 13.1213C3.75736 14 5.17157 14 8 14H10" stroke="#141B34" stroke-width="1.5" stroke-linecap="round" />
                  <path d="M10 16C10 13.1716 10 11.7574 10.8787 10.8787C11.7574 10 13.1716 10 16 10C18.8284 10 20.2426 10 21.1213 10.8787C22 11.7574 22 13.1716 22 16C22 18.8284 22 20.2426 21.1213 21.1213C20.2426 22 18.8284 22 16 22C13.1716 22 11.7574 22 10.8787 21.1213C10 20.2426 10 18.8284 10 16Z" stroke="#141B34" stroke-width="1.5" />
                  <path d="M4 16.5C4 17.9045 4 18.6067 4.33706 19.1111C4.48298 19.3295 4.67048 19.517 4.88886 19.6629C5.39331 20 6.09554 20 7.5 20" stroke="#141B34" stroke-width="1.5" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
                  <path d="M20 7.5C20 6.09554 20 5.39331 19.6629 4.88886C19.517 4.67048 19.3295 4.48298 19.1111 4.33706C18.6067 4 17.9045 4 16.5 4" stroke="#141B34" stroke-width="1.5" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
                </svg>
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, understood that ```display: hidden;``` will just hide it and the space will till be taken.
This answer will help me a lot in future projects as well so thanks a lot!!